# Guess a number game, score counter giving incorrect result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a simple 1 - 10 guess the number game with Javascript.
It can be viewed here [Guessing game](http://www.ysk.co.za/guessing/index.html) 
 
To add up score i have a `var score = 4` which de-increments each time the number guessed (with a `for` loop which is smaller than 5) incorrect. I `+=` to `var tally` and display `tally` as score. 
My problem is `score` always equals 0, and therefore does not add anything to tally, I am struggling to find a solution. 
My javascript is:

```
var tally;
function play() {

    var compNum = (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(0);
    var score = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            var userNum = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
        } else {
            if (userNum < compNum) {
                userNum = prompt("Guess higher, you have " + (4 - i) + " turns left ", userNum);
            } else if (userNum > compNum) {
                userNum = prompt("Guess lower you have " + (4 - i) + " turns left ", userNum);
            }
        }
        score--;

    }

    tally += score;
    $("#score").html("score: " + tally);


    if (i >= 3 && userNum != compNum) {
        var again = confirm("Sorry you lost. The number was: " + compNum + " Play again?");
    } else if (userNum == compNum) {
        again = confirm("Well done! play again?");
        i <= 5;
    }
    if (again) {
        play();
    }
    if (userNum == "") {
        i <= 5;
    }


}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="play()">PLAY</button>
<div id="score"></div>
```

Your help is really appreciated

Comment: What is `i <= 5;` supposed to be doing? Should it be a decrement?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP it is so the `for` loop does not repeat when the answer is correct. is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You don't appear to be even checking if the user has the right answer in your loop. You need to check and exit the loop if they have the right answer with `break`. Otherwise your loop will always run to completion and `score` will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the number entered by the use is equal to the random one and if that is the case exit form the for loop.
With your code the loop runs the whole 4 times,

Comment: And I'll show that your answer is basically the same as my comment that I made before I added my answer *with* code and before your answer.

Comment: I  know it is actually the same answer. I did not read the answers before I posted. Sorry man,

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you need to check if the user has the right answer and exit the loop if they do.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    if (i == 0) {
        var userNum = +prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
    } else {
        if (userNum < compNum) {
            userNum = prompt("Guess higher, you have " + (4 - i) + " turns left ", userNum);
        } else if (userNum > compNum) {
            userNum = prompt("Guess lower you have " + (4 - i) + " turns left ", userNum);
        }
    }
    if (userNum === compNum) {
        // they guessed right, so exit the loop
        break;
    }
    score--;

}
```

In addition, I'd check to see if `isNaN(userNum)` to check your user actually entered a number. It's up to you if you want to give them another chance if they don't.